# Is Cersei actually pregnant?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The woods witch, Maggy the Frog, prophesied to a teenage Cersei that she would have only three children, and that each would die before their mother.

If Cersei is really with child, can she carry to term in spite of this prediction? If not, why would she lie?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79503/could-she-really-be-pregnant

Comment: `Why would she lie?`: The same reason most of what she says is a lie - To get people to trust her and manipulate them into a position she wants them in.

Comment: Re "why would she lie" - look at the effect it had on Jaime and Tyrion: it made them soften their positions, trust her more and believe she had motives other than seeking power. If it was a lie it was a really smart one

Comment: Cersei already had a black-haired child with Robert (she tells this to Catelyn in S01E02), so this is already her fifth child!
So I think the prophesy was either not true, or the prophesy was talking about children that make it out of infancy, which might mean this child will not survive very long...

Comment: This is just speculation until we see the next season - _if_ that gets confirmed, _if_ she doesn't die first

Comment: Clearly speculative and therefore opinion based.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - She did seem to conveniently break it out, to great success, whenever Jamie was wavering in his unflagging support...right up until that last one, which proved to be too much even for him. I'd also guess she wouldn't keep it, if true. An incest baby, while a useful tool in manipulating Jamie, loses her Euron and his fleet if she starts to show.

Comment: *THIS* is the *valonqar* that ends her life

Comment: This is a good question ! I had this doubt too, if Cercei is actually bluffing to have a hold of the men in her life

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think she is. As we see in the season 7 finale, her pregnancy had an effect on her decision to deal with Jaime's supposed betrayal (the way she sees it):

> J: Are you going to order him to kill me? I'm the only one you have left. Our children are gone, our father is gone. It's just me and you now.
>
> S: There's one more yet to come.

At this time, her intentions had been already revealed and there was no reason for her to lie or manipulate anyone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64807/discussion-between-thelethalcoder-and-madmada).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I believe she is playing Tyrion and Jaime. The "after show behind the scenes" segment referred to this.

Comment: Can you add evidence of the after show behind the scenes referring to this?

Comment: At 3.34 of the HBO "extras" for the episode, David Benioff says that it seems Cersei is bluffing (they show her touching her stomach while talking to Tyrion) and that Tyrion might be falling for her bluff when he comments that she is pregnant.

Comment: I agree with you. It's not coincidence that she needs Jamie and Tyrion to be in her court and then she comes out with the I'm pregnant news. Shes most likely lying to the men(Jamie, euron) to have a hold over them giving them hope of a baby.